# jQuery toc generation without plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to generate a kind toc for a html document with jQuery - without
using any plugins. I'm just starting to learn/improve my jQuery know-how.

HTML input:

```
<div id="toc"></div>
<h3><a name="construction-block"></a>Construction Block</h3><p>...</p>
<h3><a name="construction-box"></a>Construction Box</h3><p>...</p>
...
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#toc").append('<p>table of contents:</p>');
$("h3").each(function(i) {
    var current = $(this);
    $("#toc").append("<h3>"+current.html()+"</h3>");
});
})
```

HTML output

```
<div id="toc">
<p>table of contents:</p>
<h3>
<a name="construction-block"></a>
Construction Block
</h3>
<h3>
<a name="construction-box"></a>
Construction Boxk
</h3>
</div>
```

It's only partial success.

Desired HTML output

```
<div id="toc">
<p>table of contents:</p>
<h3>
<a href="#construction-block">Construction Block</a>
</h3>
<h3>
<a href="#construction-box">Construction Box</a>
</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to copy the `h3` element's text into a table of contents and create a link to the original `h3`?

Comment: Stupid me... Desired Output should be <p>... not <h3>. Will change $("#toc").append("<h3>"+current.html()+"</h3>");
to $("#toc").append("<p>"+current.html()+"</p>");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following (given some changes in the HTML):

```
$('<p />', {
    'text': 'Table of contents'
}).appendTo('#toc');
$('<ol />').appendTo('#toc');

$('h3').each(
    function() {
        var that = this,
            $that = $(that),
            a = $('<a />', {
                'href': '#' + that.id,
                'text': $that.text()
            }),
            li = $('<li />').append(a).appendTo('#toc ol');
    });​
```

This jQuery creates an ordered list (which is, essentially, a semantic definition of what a table of contents *is*), and appends the text of the `h3` elements to a new `a` element within newly-created, and appended, list-items.

The HTML changes are the removal of the `<a>` elements, since the `id` can (and *should*) be used instead of named anchors (and this also works in IE).

The new HTML:

```
<div id="toc"></div>
<h3 id="construction-block">Construction Block</h3>
<p>...</p>
<h3 id="construction-box">Construction Box</h3>
<p>...</p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jRtsH/).

I didn't think of this until now, but you could achieve the same even without `id` attributes on the `h3` elements, and simply use the jQuery to create the relevant `id` attributes as it goes:

```
$('<p />', {
    'text': 'Table of contents'
}).appendTo('#toc');
$('<ol />').appendTo('#toc');

$('h3').each(
    function(i,el) {
        var $that = $(el),
            text = $that.text(),
            id = text.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/,'-');
        el.id = id;
        var a = $('<a />', {
            'href' : '#' + id,
            'text' : text
        }),
            li = $('<li />').append(a).appendTo('#toc ol');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jRtsH/1/).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [jQuery (how to create elements with jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).
- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Helped me a lot to understand - also to use prependTo.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of some help! =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#toc").append("<h3>").text(current.html());
```